# iptables - websites redirection

Tags: iptables, http, route

I have three servers.
The first is a for my front 
the two other http server : for dispatch.

I want for example, do :
receive a request on my front (public) : site1.com an redirect the request on server1 (private)
receive a request on my front (public) : site2.com an redirect the request on server2 (private)

idem for ftp : 
ftp.site1.com redirect on server1
ftp.site2.com redirect on server2

possible ?

Comment: You really ought to use a proper load balancer for this, not iptables.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question properly. I think editing DNS records would do the wanted behaviour. I may be rude but my advice would be to read this: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-English-Punctuation-Correctly

Comment: It is possible that he actually wants only the front server to have DNS records and the other 2 servers just acting as backend servers. This happens more.

Comment: Since iptables doesn't understand http protocol, it won't work properly. You need apache + mod_proxy or another reverse proxy (haproxy, nginx).

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible:

```
# Enable routing.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21
```

this will forward packets to ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 21. 
u can leave the :$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination

For http requests I would suggest mod_proxy instead of iptables.

Comment: yes but... it s for all packed ... i want for one site transfert packed on one server, and if it s the second website, redirect on the other server.